# Kubernetes - Deployment - Configure livenessProbe

Tags: kubernetes

I can't configure a livenessProbe with attributes for a k8s Deployment, I tried apiVersion: apps/v1beta1, or apps/v1 or apps/v1beta2 or apps/v1beta3.

I want to add the attributes :

- initialDelaySeconds
- periodSeconds
- timeoutSeconds

If I define any of these attributes I get an error

> unknown field "periodSeconds" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.HTTPGetAction

Comment: Can you share the YAML manifest please, otherwise it's really hard to tell what's going on?

Comment: if I have to take a guess, you did not indented the value properly

Comment: Yes indentation would be my guess as well, hence asking for the YAML ;)

That, or defined on the pod-level rather than container-level …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work: **`extensions/v1beta1`** for kind Deployment. It is working well for me.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    labels:
    app: myapp
    name: appapppod
    .
    .
    .
       livenessProbe:
         httpGet:
           path: /com/livenessstatus
           port: 7080
           scheme: HTTPS
           httpHeaders:
           - name: Your_customer_header_if_any
             value: my_customer_header_value
         initialDelaySeconds: 120
         timeoutSeconds: 40
         periodSeconds: 90
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes it was the indent level thanks a lot, and it's correct on the documentation so I think this question isn't useful in general sorry

Comment: I did the same and was misleaded by the message as well. It works since `periodicSenconds` is no more inside `httpGet`.
Thank you